# How to get high quality video after merge into one

Tags: ffmpeg

I follow the page [Create a mosaic out of several input videos](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) to merge videos. But，I got poor video quality. How can I get the video same as the original.

```
ffmpeg
-i 1.flv-i 2.flv -i 3.flv -i 4.flv
-filter_complex "
    nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
    [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
    [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
    [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
    [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
    [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
    [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
    [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
    [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
"
-f flv rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live2
```

And when I use rtmp://** as video input.
Such as:

```
    ffmpeg-i rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live1 -i rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live1 -i rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live1 -i rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live1
-filter_complex "
    nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];
    [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
    [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];
    [2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];
    [3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];
    [base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];
    [tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];
    [tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];
    [tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240
"
-f flv rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live2
```

It tells me:

```
Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description  nullsrc=size=640x480 [base];[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright];[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft];[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright];[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1];[tmp1][upperright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2];[tmp2][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3];[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240 matches no streams.
```

Is that a bug? but I use the newest ffmepg.
[bug](https://github.com/moviemasher/moviemasher.rb/issues/9)

And I can only use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live10 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv output.flv
```

to transfer rtmp into flv,and then read flv video...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're outputting to FLV and haven't specified an encoder, ffmpeg is selecting `flv1`. By default, it will use a target bitrate of 200 kbps.

So, you can set a quality scale target, e.g.

```
... -q:v 5 -f flv rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live2
```

or wsitch to x264, whose defaults should be fine

```
... -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://10.240.209.94:9999/live2
```

Comment: thank you, that works, I got a new question. Can you help me？

Comment: Hi,I add the question description. Thanks. @Mulvya

Comment: Post it as a new question.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I post a new question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628034/merge-rtmp-video-stream-specifier-v-in-filtergraph-description